# What counts towards your 'fear' rating in AC:BF?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag, ubisoft-connect

While playing Black Flag, I have noticed that a Uplay notification occasionally appears, usually when I have finished a mission commenting

> 'You are the x most feared pirate'

How is this calculated?
Does it have to do with the number of ships that you sink, or your progression tracker stats?

Basically how is it counted that you the nth most feared pirate?

Comment: @Frank it's more about the feedback. I want to know if my answer was helpful or comments for improvement. No Feedback drives me nuts. I'm sorry for the comments.

Comment: @Lokuzt I do intend to go back to AC:BF at some point and check your answer, it's come out of my PS4 since I posted the question, and haven't found the time to check. Fear not - I will feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look under **"Database"** and there's a section labeled **"Leaderboards"**.

It tells you what each of the titles (most feared/prosperous Pirate/deadliest Assassin) means in terms of what's being measured.

> Your rank is basically where you sit on the leaderboard.
>
> And from what I know **Most Feared Pirate** is from destroying ships!
>
> So the more ships you destroy the more you climb on the **Most Feared
> Pirate** Leaderboard.

**EDIT**

For a more complete answer:

The **Most Prosperous Pirate** is for the amount of money you plundered throughout the game

and **Deadliest Assassin** is for most people assassinated.

Hope I Helped!

Comment: On the "most feared pirates" leaderboard it states "This leaderboard tracks the total number of ships sunk", so you are right.